# undefined PATHS in getStaticPaths Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to do `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` but I'm always getting an error that the `paths` is undefined in `getStaticPaths`. Next version is currently on `10.0.3`.

This is the error message

```
Error: Invalid value returned from getStaticPaths in /properties/[id]. Received undefined Expected: { paths: [], fallback: boolean }
```

Here's my code

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  try {
    const properties = await api.get('/properties', {
      headers: generateAuthHeaders(null, 'application/json', API_TOKEN)
    })

    const paths = properties.res.data.propertyDetails.map(value => {
      return {
        params: { id: value.id }
      }
    })

    return { paths, fallback: false }
  } catch (er) {
    //  do nothing
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  try {
    const properties = await api.get(`/properties/${params.id}`, {
      headers: generateAuthHeaders(null, 'application/json', API_TOKEN)
    })

    return {
      props: {
        propertyDetails: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(properties.data.properties))
      }
    }
  } catch (er) {
    return {
      props: { propertyDetails: false }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess from looking at the code is that the catch block in `getStaticPaths` is being entered, and as it has no return statement the function ends and returns `undefined` by default.

So you need to return something, like this...

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  try {
    const properties = await api.get('/properties', {
      headers: generateAuthHeaders(null, 'application/json', API_TOKEN)
    })

    const paths = properties.res.data.propertyDetails.map(value => {
      return {
        params: { id: value.id }
      }
    })

    return { paths, fallback: false }
  } catch (er) {
    console.error(er)
    return { paths: [], fallback: false } // <- ADDED RETURN STMNT
  }
}
```

I am not familiar with the `getStaticPaths` API, so you may need to return *something* (not an empty array) for `paths`. So this code may well not work, but I'm just pointing out that you need to return an object in the form specified in the error message you are receiving.

Comment: thank you for your answer, though it's still not working :((

Comment: @ayabbear what error is being printed to the console?

Comment: that's actually one of the challenge i have is that as far as i know, it's not allowed to print outputs on console, something about its features. but what i did try is removing the try catch and with `return { paths: [{ params: { id: 'abc' } }], fallback: false }` it's working, i think what i need to do is to pattern my `paths` to that same static data i did but i'm not sure how it should be done with multiple `id`